# Meaning of "level"

Tags: meaning

> A scale is a range of levels or numbers used for measuring something.

How do you define *level* here?

Comment: How can this be anything except [General Reference?](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=level&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=QMcvUNDpEaG50QWshYDoDA&ved=0CGQQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c9ee3c93c5244606&biw=1469&bih=886)

Comment: I think the question must be improved in order to not fall intot he category of a general reference question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Level](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/level)* here means:

> : a position in a scale or rank (as of achievement, significance, or
>   value)

- *funded at the national level*
- *the job appeals to me on many levels*

---

You might also look to video games, where Level 1 is fairly easy, and Level 60 is not.

Comment: position here basically means where it is located right?

Comment: @Theo yes.  You can also refer to it as a *rank*.  For instance, I play a MMORPG on a certain server that keeps track of my *rank*.  I type 'place' and it shows my total points, and then my *rank* or *place* among all of the users, for example, 987 of 18,393.  My *position* is 987th of 18,393.